# For loop from a continous position

Tags: logic, procedural-programming

I have a matrix A, which has its elements being function of m,  say

```
A[m_]={m, -m*m+2, 5x+m, 3*m+2, -m*m*m, -3+m, m, 5*m*m-4*m, 2*m*m*m}
```

Now, there is a double For loop, as

```
For[m = 1, m < 6, m++, 
 For[k = 1, k < 9, k++, 
  If[A[m][[k]] < 0, Print[A[m][[k]], m]; Break[]]]]
```

This loop is meant to pick elements of the A one by one, if this element is negative, m -> m++ and A is calculated for new m value and so on..

My problem is that for every loop for m, k loop starts from 1. But I want it to start from next element for next cycle.

For example, for m = 1 loop, first negative element (-m*m+2) of A is at second position (k=2)  so first o/p of code is 0. Now for next cycle of m, I want k to start values from element which is already picked, so it should start from 3, not from 1. 
Similarly after m = 2 loop, which has negative element at position 4, I want m = 3 cycle to start from k = 5 and so on...
Would appreciate any help on this
thanks

Comment: Just a note. [Your life will be better without for loops](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/38205)

Comment: Can I achieve same o/p without FOR loop ??

Comment: Yeah. See `Table` and `Do`. They're similar, but *much* nicer to work with. They're also faster and `Table`  is often much faster as it auto-compiles.

Comment: "Now for next cycle of m, I want k to start values from element which is already picked,".   ?cant understand that at all..?

Comment: BTW for the `m = 1` loop, the first negative element is `-m^3 == -1` at k == 5` (not `(-m*m+2)`). Also, I'm assuming the `x` in position 3 is a typo and can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm not entirely clear what you're asking for, but maybe this is close.

Define you list as

```
a = {# &, 2 - #^2 &, 5 + # &, 3 # + 2 &, -#^3 &, 
       # - 3 &, # &, 5 #^2 - 4 # &, 2 #^3 &};
```

That is, `a` is a list of [`Pure Functions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html). Then you can [`Scan`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scan.html) (or [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html)) over those functions while keeping track of `m`.

```
m = 1;
Last@Reap@Scan[If[#[m] < 0, Sow[{#[m], m++}]] &, a]

(* {{{-1, 1}, {-1, 2}}} *)
```

Note that you have to initialize `m = 1`, but both `k` and the `k-th` element of `a` are now "hidden" by mapping directly over the elements of `a`.

**Explanation**

If that's all a bit opaque, have a look at the whole of the matrix you're traversing:

```
MatrixForm[Table[a[[k]][m], {m, 6}, {k, 9}]
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
 1 & 1 & 6 & 5 & -1 & -2 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
 2 & -2 & 7 & 8 & -8 & -1 & 2 & 12 & 16 \\
 3 & -7 & 8 & 11 & -27 & 0 & 3 & 33 & 54 \\
 4 & -14 & 9 & 14 & -64 & 1 & 4 & 64 & 128 \\
 5 & -23 & 10 & 17 & -125 & 2 & 5 & 105 & 250 \\
 6 & -34 & 11 & 20 & -216 & 3 & 6 & 156 & 432 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and include a bit more commentary in the above function:

```
m = 1;
Reap@(
  With[{fun = #},
     Print[ToString[{m, fun[m]}]];
     If[fun[m] < 0, Sow[{fun[m], m++}]]
     ] & /@ a)

(* {1, 1}    
   {1, 1}    
   {1, 6}    
   {1, 5}    
   {1, -1}    
   {2, -1}    
   {3, 3}    
   {3, 33}    
   {3, 54}

   {{Null, Null, Null, Null, {-1, 1}, {-1, 2}, Null, Null, Null}, 
   {{{-1, 1}, {-1, 2}}}} *)
```

So you can see how the function moves across the top row of the matrix -- 1, 1, 6, 5 -- but nothing happens (all those `Null`s) until it hits the first -1 in the fifth position. The function then [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html)s the value of that function at that `m`-value -- `a[[5]][1] == -1` -- and the `m`-value, which it then increments. Then it's on row 2 in the sixth position, where there's another -1, which also gets `Sow`n, along with `m == 2`. `m` is incremented again, and reaches the end of `a` with `m == 3` as there are no more negatives. Those `Sow`n values are collected by the [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) at the start.